# Can't find an installed program - mathematica

Tags: bash, software-installation

I recently installed Wolfram Mathematica as a .sh file. I ran it using bash and it took me through installation. It said that the installation directory should be

```
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1
```

and my scripts would be placed in

```
/usr/local/bin
```

It then said installation complete.

I typed

```
mathematica
```

into the terminal and it returned

```
mathematica: command not found
```

I have looked for the directory /usr/local/Wolfram and it does not exist and I have rebooted my computer. I looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490507/cant-find-programs-i-installed) question and 'which' has not helped me with keywords 'mathematica' or 'wolfram'. How do I find the program and run it?

Comment: @JacobVlijm. Unfortunately I have it through my university which is incredibly annoying because I guess it's not particularly reproducible. I don't know if you have any other ideas or if I can provide any more information?

Comment: result of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: You are telling your "mathematica " script should have been placed in /usr/local/bin but you are not finding this,find it by the command "sudo find / -name mathematica" and tell me the result

Comment: @NewUSer I am new to Ubuntu so hopefully this is what you wanted: I opened a new terminal and typed `echo $PATH' and it returned: ``/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games''

Comment: Sorry for my inability to codify in comments. Trying to work it out.

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1`?

Comment: @JacobVlijm  In /usr/local I have ''bin  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src''. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @saptarshinag I tried sudo find and not much happened. I tried find and got a huge list of stuff. Should I add it to the question?

Comment: @NewUSer The output is: ls: cannot access /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok then friend I suppose there was an another error please run your script again. sudo bash mathematica.sh`

Comment: @JacobVlijm Do you mean where my .sh file is? It's on my desktop and there is no .desktop file. IS that what you mean? Sorry for being slow.

Comment: @NewUSer Rerunning the .sh file.

Comment: @Matta please post the output after correct installation if the problem persists

Comment: The problem is resolved. The first installation simply didn't work. Thank you very much for your time Jacob Vlijm, saptarshi nag and New USer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case:

```
ls -l /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1
```

gives

```
ls: cannot access /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1: No such file or directory
```

This leads to conclusion that some error happen and you don't really install it.

so rerun the script again as mentioned [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12453)

```
sudo bash installer.sh
```

and follow instructions carefully and its better to keep the default settings

Comment: Before, I ran `bash installer.sh` and the second time I ran `sudo bash installer.sh`. Also the previous time I accidentally hit a random key on my keyboard whilst it was installing. I wouldn't expect either of these to have an effect but maybe they did.  Other than that there may have been other reasons it failed. Anyway it works now. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: you are welcome and glad for you and have nice time